# How to handle sign in and sign out functionalities for more than one "thing"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9. In my application I would like to handle sign in and sign out functionalities for more than one "thing" since, other than classic users, "other things" can sign in and sign out. I thought to implement one "dedicated" REST-ful `sessions_controller` for each thing that can authenticate, maybe by making something like the following in the `config/routes.rb` file:

```
# Before:
# resources :users
# resources :other_things

# After:
resources :users do
  resource :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => 'users/sessions'
end
resources :other_things do
  resource :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => 'other_things/sessions'
end
```

With the above code I am trying to "separate" / "namespace" authentication concerns for users and other things. However, unlike the above code makes, I would like to match sign in and sign out URLs as the following:

```
localhost/users/sign_in
localhost/users/sign_out
localhost/other_things/sign_in
localhost/other_things/sign_out
```

How *should* I proceed? What do you advice about?

Comment: Are you sure these things can't be converted to a user? Maybe different types of users?

Comment: @MurifoX - Yes, I am. "Things" (users and other things) are intended to be used differently and have different sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? Since there are few routes I wouldn't take time to clean it more.

```
resources :users do
  get :sign_in => 'users/sessions#new'
  post :sign_in => 'users/sessions#create'
  delete :sign_out => 'users/sessions#destroy'
end

resources :other_things do
  get :sign_in => 'other_things/sessions#new'
  post :sign_in => 'other_things/sessions#create'
  delete :sign_out => 'other_things/sessions#destroy'
end
```